# Excel to JSON Schema in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

I've got a task to generate form excelsheet where I've to design form as per the datatype provided in the excelsheet. Example:

[image]

I'm trying to make a `JSON` schema from above excel data so that I can insert it into the mongodb to generate form dynamically.

Following is code I'm trying to implement:

```
            var workbook = XLSX.readFile(req.file.path);
            //console.log(workbook);
            var result = {};
            workbook.SheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName) {
                var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[sheetName]);
                if (roa.length > 0) {
                    result = roa;
                }
            });
            //return result;
            //console.log(result);

            var jsonData = {};
            var dropdown = {};
            var attrTypes = result[0];
            //console.log(attrTypes);

            for (var i = 1; i < result.length; i++) {
                var obj = result[i];
                //console.log(obj);
                for (var key in obj) {
                    var attrName = key;
                    var attrValue = obj[key];
                    if (attrTypes[attrName]) {
                        var type = attrTypes[attrName].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, ''); // Means type is given                        
                        //console.log(type);

                        if (type === "selectbox") {
                            console.log(attrValue);
                            //var dropdown = attrValue;
                            //console.log(dropdown);
                        }

                    } else {
                        //console.log(type); // Means type is not given
                        jsonData = attrName + ":" + attrValue;
                        //console.log(jsonData);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Expected `JSON` output:

```
[
{
    Number : 1,
    FirstName : "Abc",
    LastName : "Xyza",
    Dept: ['Finance','Health','Insurance'],
    Country : ['US','Australia','Canada'],
    Year : ['2014','2015','2016'],,
    DateofBirth" : new Date(1937,05,02),
    Gender : ['M','F']    
},
{
    Number : 2,
    FirstName : "Abcd",
    LastName : "Xyzb",
    Dept: ['Finance','Health','Insurance'],
    Country : ['US','Australia','Canada'],
    Year : ['2014','2015','2016'],,
    DateofBirth" : new Date(1948,10,27),
    Gender : ['M','F']    
}
        .
        .
        and so on
]
```

Above is the code I'm trying to implement in MEANSTACK.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't paste a blob of code and ask for us to debug it. What have you tried? What was the actual vs expected behavior? Error messages? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JuanMendes: Okay. Let me update a post

Comment: @JuanMendes: I've update post plz check it

Comment: The expected `Dept` value is an array? Shouldn't it be the value of the dropdown? I'd recommend converting the sheet into a regular string 2d array first then create the objects.

Comment: What is the error / problem?  The more you put into your question, the faster it gets answered.

Comment: @tyler: The problem is how can I generate json from above excel by using those datatype. Which technique I need to use here to generate that kind of output

Comment: @Mark You have a bunch of `console.log`.  Can you give us the output of those logs.  Please add some prefixs like `console.log("attrValue="+attrValue);`

Comment: In addition to RainingChain's comment, do you intend on not saving each object's spreadsheet-given value for dropdowns and radio buttons? I understand collecting a unique list of those values but this is not where you should do this in your code. Your current implementation explicitly and simultaneously sets up repeated data and data-loss for each object in your expected JSON array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the **XLSX on the client side** and other excel formats using [JS-XLSX](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library.

You don't need to store the dropdown any other values that are to be populated in the inputs multiply. They should be stored separately. So the array object should be like below

```
[   
    {  
      "Number":1,
      "FirstName":"Abc",
      "LastName":"Xyza",
      "Dept":"Finance",
      "Country":"US",
      "Year":2014,
      "DateOfBirth":19370502,
      "Gender":"M"
    },
    {  
      "Number":2,
      "FirstName":"Abcd",
      "LastName":"Xyzb",
      "Dept":"Health",
      "Country":"Australia",
      "Year":2014,
      "DateOfBirth":19481027,
      "Gender":"F"
    }
]
```

Dropdown and radio values should be stored separately like below:

```
{  
   "Dept":{  
      "type":"dropdown",
      "values":[  
         "Finance",
         "Health",
         "Insurance"
      ]
   },
   "Country":{  
      "type":"dropdown",
      "values":[  
         "US",
         "Australia",
         "Canada"
      ]
   },
   "Year":{  
      "type":"dropdown",
      "values":[  
         2014,
         2015,
         2016
      ]
   },
   "Gender":{  
      "type":"radio button",
      "values":[  
         "M",
         "F"
      ]
   }
}
```

These both can be combined one schema object as

```
//included single objects from both for brevity
jsonSchema = {
    array: [
        {  
            "Number":2,
            "FirstName":"Abcd",
            "LastName":"Xyzb",
            "Dept":"Health",
            "Country":"Australia",
            "Year":2014,
            "DateOfBirth":19481027,
            "Gender":"F"
        }
    ],
    inputs: {
        "Gender":{  
            "type":"radio button",
            "values":[  
                "M",
                "F"
            ]
        }
    }
};
```

**Note: Date type values can not be stored as date object while serializing to JSON. Those should be stored as a string or number and should be converted to Date object on client side**

I have implemented the JSON generation and Form generation in this GIT project

https://github.com/ConsciousObserver/stackoverflow/tree/master/excelTest

Following is the output screenshot.

[image: Generated Forms]

Here is the output JSON.

```
{
  "array": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "FirstName": "Abc",
      "LastName": "Xyza",
      "Dept": "Finance",
      "Country": "US",
      "Year": 2014,
      "DateOfBirth": 19370502,
      "Gender": "M"
    },
    {
      "Number": 2,
      "FirstName": "Abcd",
      "LastName": "Xyzb",
      "Dept": "Health",
      "Country": "Australia",
      "Year": 2014,
      "DateOfBirth": 19481027,
      "Gender": "F"
    },
    {
      "Number": 3,
      "FirstName": "Abce",
      "LastName": "Xyzc",
      "Dept": "Health",
      "Country": "US",
      "Year": 2015,
      "DateOfBirth": 19441029,
      "Gender": "F"
    },
    {
      "Number": 4,
      "FirstName": "Abcf",
      "LastName": "Xyzd",
      "Dept": "Insurance",
      "Country": "Canada",
      "Year": 2016,
      "DateOfBirth": 19481030,
      "Gender": "M"
    },
    {
      "Number": 5,
      "FirstName": "Abcg",
      "LastName": "Xyze",
      "Dept": "Finance",
      "Country": "Canada",
      "Year": 2016,
      "DateOfBirth": 19480604,
      "Gender": "M"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": {
    "Dept": {
      "type": "dropdown",
      "values": [
        "Finance",
        "Health",
        "Insurance"
      ]
    },
    "Country": {
      "type": "dropdown",
      "values": [
        "US",
        "Australia",
        "Canada"
      ]
    },
    "Year": {
      "type": "dropdown",
      "values": [
        2014,
        2015,
        2016
      ]
    },
    "Gender": {
      "type": "radio button",
      "values": [
        "M",
        "F"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @11thdimention: Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This project](https://github.com/ykaragol/xlsx-json) generates JSON from XLSX file. Have a look on that code.

Its written in Java. And it uses `apache.poi` to parse XLSX file and `mongodb.bson` to generate JSON. Maybe it give any helpful idea to you.

[This project](https://github.com/coolengineer/excel2json) and [this project](https://github.com/faisalman/simple-excel-js) is written in Javascript. If you search on github you may find useful codes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are confusing the concept of [schema with that of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115112/what-is-the-difference-between-schema-and-data-dictionary#answer-3119891). The department of Abc Xyza being Finance is data. That the possible values of Department given the Excel file are Finance, Health or Insurance is schema.

Here is an example: http://json-schema.org/examples.html

So if the title of the question is correct and you need a JSON schema, then I would go for functions that create array of strings from the values provided, in case of the 'dropdown' or 'radiobutton' types, determining the data type of values in columns (int for Number, string for FirstName, etc), determining the minimum and maximum values or even allowed string patterns.

The output that I envision here is something like this:

```
{
    "id" : "http://your.site/form-schema",
    "title" : "Form schema",
    "description" : "JSON schema for autogenerating forms",
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
        "Number" : {
            "type" : "integer"
        },
        "FirstName" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "LastName" : {
            "type" : "string"
        },
        "Dept" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "oneOf" : [
                        { "format" : "Finance"},
                        { "format" : "Health" },
                        { "format" : "Insurance" }
            ]
        },
        "Country" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "oneOf" : [
                        {"format" : "US" },
                        { "format" : "Australia" },
                        { "format" : "Canada" }
            ]
        },
        "Year" : {
            "type" : "integer",
            "oneOf" : [
                        { "format" : "2014" },
                        { "format" : "2015" },
                        { "format" : "2016" }
            ]
        },
        "DateofBirth" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "pattern" : "yyyyMMdd"
        },
        "Gender" : {
            "enum" : ["M", "F"]
        }
    },
    "required" : ["Number", "FirstName", "LastName"],
    "additionalProperties" : false
}
```